# How to unzip s3 file through lambda and chain with other lambda functions using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Two Issues over here:-
I have a zip file which once uploaded to s3 should trigger an event and 
1. unzip the file
2. After unzip second lambda should trigger and call api.

Comment: What are the triggers for both? Are they being uploaded to a specific prefix?

Comment: What is your actual question? The title mentions chaining Lambda functions, but the question talks about "unzip to s3 still needs a solution". Feel free to Edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an AWS Lambda function to "unzip to S3", then the Lambda function would need to:

- Download the Zip file to local storage
- Unzip the files
- Loop through the files and upload each one to Amazon S3

Please note that there is a **maximum of 500MB of disk storage space** available to Lambda functions (in the `/tmp/` directory), and this space needs to hold both the zip file and the extracted zip files.

Also, you'll need to extend the **timeout** setting to give adequate time for the function to perform all of the above operations.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer might work but the tmp folder has limited memory so it might cause problems as your file size gets increased. Instead, you can create an event based trigger that runs a Lambda function. This Lambda can then read zip files into a buffer (instead of downloading them locally), unzip them using the zipfile library and upload the unzipped files back to s3. Here's a detailed tutorial here: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9

You should increase the timeout and memory size both to the max.